# Delete node in linked list result in program collapse

Tags: c++, linked-list, delete-operator

I was trying to delete a node in a linked list defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    char key[10];
    char name[20];
    int age;
}Data;

typedef struct Node
{
    Data nodeData;
    struct Node *nextNode;
}cltype;
```

And the the delete function is defined as below:

```
int clDeleteNode(cltype *head, char *key)
{
    cltype *node, *htemp = new (cltype);
    htemp = head;
    node = head;
    while (htemp)
    {
        if (strcmp(htemp->nodeData.key, key))
        {
            node->nextNode = htemp->nextNode;
            delete htemp;
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            node = htemp;
            htemp = htemp->nextNode;
        }
    }
    //delete mp
    return 0;
}
```

And the problem is when I tried to invoke the the delete function in this form the program will collapse:

```
    cout << "program demo for deleting node\n" << "input key:" << endl;
    fflush(stdin);
    cin >> key;
    //scanf("%s", key);
    //int i = 
    if (clDeleteNode(head, key))
    {
        cout << "Delete Successful" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Operation Failed" << endl;
    }
    clAllNode(head);
```

The screen will display "Delete Successful", but the clAllNode(...) function will not execute.And the clAllNode(...) functions works totally well at other place, so I guess there is something wrong with the delete operation,can someone tell me where I did wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Your method cannot correctly delete the head of the list. You don't even need to debug it, just look at the function signature.

Comment: Deleting a node should not involve allocating anything - `new (cltype)` is a memory leak. Also, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined. (Is there a "tutorial" somewhere that teaches people to do that?)

Comment: ... and you're attempting to delete the first node that *doesn't* contain `key`.

Comment: Thanks molbdnilo, I figured I should use if (strcmp(htemp->nodeData.key, key) == 0)